# Does anyone know what is the ``name`` argument in Zookeeper's AsyncCallback.StringCallback processResult() method?

Tags: apache-zookeeper

The [API docs](http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.4.5/api/org/apache/zookeeper/AsyncCallback.StringCallback.html#processResult%28int,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29) are not very enlightening on the subject, and a few Google queries have not yielded much success.

I even have the [Zookeeper O'Reilly book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920028901.do), but it appears to be using an older version of the API and I have the distinct impression that this was added recently.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The synchronous [create()](http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.4.5/api/org/apache/zookeeper/ZooKeeper.html#create%28java.lang.String,%20byte%5B%5D,%20java.util.List,%20org.apache.zookeeper.CreateMode%29) method return a String, so the asynchronous [create()](http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.4.5/api/org/apache/zookeeper/ZooKeeper.html#create%28java.lang.String,%20byte%5B%5D,%20java.util.List,%20org.apache.zookeeper.CreateMode,%20org.apache.zookeeper.AsyncCallback.StringCallback,%20java.lang.Object%29) method accepts a StringCallback method, where the name is the return value of the synchronous method.

The create() methods need to return a String since if you create a Sequential ZNode, the caller doesn't know the name of the path they created.